# joomla password stored differently

Tags: joomla, hash, md5, salt

A Joomla website came to my hands to fix some login issue that new users had when attempting to login.

The users are registered manually in the backoffice.

What i noticed is that last months, passwords were stores in data base like simple md5 encryption.

Now they are encrypted with {hash}:{salt}.

I dont know what happens, but now when the users try to login and the script

... password = '" . md5($_POST['password']) ...

runs, it gives "Wrong password".

I've searched but couldnt find nothing that could helped me.

It seams that something changed, and i would like to understand what changed and why, and how to put the password encryption on md5 again, cause all the user database is in md5

thank you

Comment: From what I can find, Joomla has used md5+salt since early in the 1.5 series. What version of Joomla is the site? Are there any other extensions (I.e. forum) that may also allow registration?

Comment: Are you using a non core authentication plugin?

Comment: The vertion is  1.7.2

About the extention i cant access the extention page, as i click on the extention menu i'm redirected to  /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer

The passwords are now stored like
2d5bc664f763be20f7b1d73106eb642f:QL3QEDx2HE5e6SjWIORYhNkBMwFbvgvb 

but the same password
was once stores in database like 
cc6c58dd4e4586e68a4129f59e68f8af